# One-liner for creating a variable based on the sum of other variables defined in a regular expression?

Tags: python, r, regex, pandas

I'm pretty good with R and just starting out trying to teach myself python.  I'm trying to replicate the following lines of code:

```
regex <- paste0("precip_pday_", 30:185, collapse = "|")
dat$TAP <- rowSums(dat[,grepl(regex, colnames(dat))])/1000
```

Basically just create a regular expression, and then take the row-wise sum of the variables with that match the regex.  I suppose I could have as just as easily not collapsed the string and used `%in%`.

I tried to replicate this in python, and the best I can do is a nested mess of for loops and if statements that takes 15 lines:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
regex = re.compile("precip")
idx = []
for i in range(0, len(list(df))-1, 1):
    name = list(df)[i]
    found = regex.findall(name)
    if len(found) > 0:
        day = name.split("_")[2]
        if int(day) in range(30, 185, 1):
            idx.append(i)

cols_I_want = df.iloc[:,idx]
df["TAP"] = cols_I_want.sum(axis = 1)/1000
```

How could this be simplified?  Made more efficient?

Here's a fake dataset, to complete the MWE:

```
fake_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000*365), nrow = 1000, ncol = 365))
colnames(fake_df) <- paste0("precip_pday_", 1:365)
write.csv("fake_df.csv")
df <- read.csv("fake_df.csv")
```

and of course

```
df = pd.read_csv("fake_df.csv")
```

Here's what part of `df` looks like:

```
ddd.iloc[[1,2,3],[1,2, 365]
]
Out[58]: 
   precip_pday_1  precip_pday_2  precip_pday_365
1       -1.189000       -0.825324          0.300221
2       -1.045318       -1.092792          1.098239
3        1.429858        0.919119         -0.643524
```

It has columns for each day of the year (and lots of others in my real dataset, but I can filter them out with the regex).

The desired output is the sum of the values of days 30 through 185

Comment: Can you show the contents of `fake_df.csv` , or perhaps a small sample with desired output?

Comment: `df.sum(axis=1) ?`

Comment: Yeah but I want only days 30 through 185.  And I want to do this via regex because the real dataset has columns besides `precip` -- I want to filter those out

Comment: `cols = ['precip_pday_'+str(i) for i in range(30,186)]` then `df[cols].sum(1)`

Comment: Thanks!  Putting for loops in the middle of an expression like that is something that doesn't work in R, but I can see how it makes sense.

Comment: `df.loc[:, 'precip_pday_30':'precip_pday_185'].sum(axis=1)` would also work.

Comment: That's called `list comprehension` in Python, and I would advise against comparing them too much.. they are *pretty* different languages. Also, I've noticed you talking about [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) but I didn't see you using it actually ;) Maybe you weren't refering to the actual concept but to the fact that there is a prefix in every column? @user2285236 that would work if you assume columns are sorted and there are no column in between 30 and 185

Comment: No I don't exactly need regex in this specific example, but in similar applications I want to match all columns that match a regex and also have a certain range of suffixes.  This simple MWE was all precip.

Comment: And I did use regex in the python example that I mocked up

Comment: @generic_user You might want to look at the [filter method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) which accepts regexes to select columns.